# How access array with specials characters in array key

Tags: typo3, fluid

I tried to wrap my mind round how to decompose a value of an array where the key is a string containing special characters.

[image: <f:debug> output of parent]

`parent.child.` does give the five entries that I don't need :-)

`parent.child.http://...` doesn't work, I think because if the special characters.

Is there a way to escape that array index string?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: We're programmers, we can read. Please read about [why you shouldn’t upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a custom ViewHelper. One example is kind of just copy paste + adjusting the namespace, from powermail: https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Classes/ViewHelpers/Misc/VariableInVariableViewHelper.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace In2code\Powermail\ViewHelpers\Misc;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\Exception\PropertyNotAccessibleException;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\ViewHelperInterface;

/**
 * Class VariableInVariableViewHelper
 */
class VariableInVariableViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper implements ViewHelperInterface
{
    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    /**
     * Initialize arguments.
     */
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        parent::initializeArguments();
        $this->registerArgument('obj', 'mixed', 'Object', true);
        $this->registerArgument('prop', 'string', 'Property', true);
    }

    /**
     * Solution for {outer.{inner}} call in fluid
     *
     * @param array $arguments
     * @param \Closure $renderChildrenClosure
     * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @throws PropertyNotAccessibleException
     */
    public static function renderStatic(
        array $arguments,
        \Closure $renderChildrenClosure,
        RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
    ) {
        $obj = $arguments['obj'];
        $prop = $arguments['prop'];
        if (is_array($obj) && array_key_exists($prop, $obj)) {
            return $obj[$prop];
        }
        if (is_object($obj)) {
            return ObjectAccess::getProperty($obj, GeneralUtility::underscoredToLowerCamelCase($prop));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to prepare your data in the controller to a more "suitable" format.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you hide the most important thing - the key value. However as we can see it's a URL with a domain name it's quite obvious it contains a dot inside, which is the problem.

Literally, the Fluid tries to access the array structure like it was nested one level deeper, so instead of

`$array['http://example.com/path/to/your/script']` it tries to access
`$array['http://example']['com/path/to/your/script']`.

You don't mention what is the clue of using such complicated keys for your array, anyway you need to get rid of the special chars to make it work.

One way is converting that structure in your controller, before assigning to the view. It's a simple `foreach()`, so I won't write it, but you need to get a structure like (pseudo code)

```php
$array = [
    'xml_base' => '',
    'children' => [
        'http_domain_com_path_to_your_script' = [
             'url' => 'http://example.com/path/to/your/script',
             'other' => 'attr',
        ],
        'http_another_com_path_to_your_script' = [
             'url' => 'http://another.com/path/to/your/script',
             'other' => 'attr',
        ],
    ]
]
```

and access it as `parent.children.http_domain_com_path_to_your_script`

or even convert it to the non-associative array

```php
$array = [
    'xml_base' => '',
    'children' => [
        [
            'url' => 'http://example.com/path/to/your/script',
            'other' => 'attr',
        ],
        [
            'url' => 'http://another.com/path/to/your/script'
            'other' => 'attr',
        ],
    ]
]
```

So you can access it by numeric values like `parent.children.0`

Finally, you can also check Georg's solution, which allows accessing such keys, anyway didn't test ever, and personally I prefer way with simplified keys.

Comment: Hi, I'm evaluting Georg's solution att he moment, will report when it's working.Or  not :-)
Its a feed with Job-Offerings from german HR-Tool heroes.
Yes, ts an URL, I think it's the namespace of heroes customs tags embedded in the feed. 
I'm fetching it with with EXT:rss_display 5.0.0 on latest  TYPO3 9.5.
EXT:rss_display uses SimplePIE, and there data is there, I can browse with via <f:debug> completely. So before patching rss_display or the underlaying SimplePIE, i hope there i a more high level solution... 

Thanks for your answer, will evaluate in the evening.

Comment: @JanSiepmann optionally you can also iterate `parent.child` array in your template, anyway it would be easier for us to add some suggestions if you described your need little bit more ;)

Answer (score 0):

Georg Ringer's suggestion got me on the right track. I added a custom Viewhelper to to acccess the custom rss tags via SimplePIE. It takes the namespace and that tag I need and return the desired values.

Thank you all very much for your help.